# How do I get my little spaceship to flip on it's Y-Axis?

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

Below is the code I'm using. Basically, it is a ball with the sprite of a tiny
spaceship that rotates around a ring. It has a trail renderer attached and
when I change the direction the trail comes out the top in the wrong direction.
I need to know how to flip the ship to match the trail.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
       
    }

    public void ChangeDirection()
    {
        _speed = -_speed;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to pinpoint ur error without knowing further details.
Is your "ball" a 3D Sphere or a 2D Circle?
What component is used to display your spaceship image?

if its the SpriteRenderer, you can get a reference to that and flip the sprite

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;
    SpriteRenderer m_SpriteRenderer;
    
    void Start()
    {
        //Fetch the SpriteRenderer from the GameObject
        m_SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
       
    }

    public void ChangeDirection()
    {
        _speed = -_speed;
        //flip sprite along the y axis
        m_SpriteRenderer.flipY = !m_SpriteRenderer.flipY
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi,

So the ball is a 2D circle.

Canvas(Circle) - Panel(Center Of Circle - Ball(With Sprite)